# Hyundai tucson 2ltr desel 56 plate problems starting

Tags: starting, diesel, hyundai, tucson

I have a genuine problem with my 56 plate Hyundai Tucson 2ltr diesel. When I bought it it ran and started great, but after about a week of using it I came out one sunny morning and it wouldn't start.

I tried the heater plugs a few times and got it started with a large amount of black smoke but soon the smoke cleared and it ran fine all day. This went on for about 5 to 6 weeks but now it will not run.

When I come to start it I turn the key and it starts on a not so good tickover between 5 and 10 on the Rev counter but that is all it will do- now it won't rev.

Someone suggested the pedal electrics so I changed the pedal but it made no difference.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! Sounds like glow plugs to me.

Comment: Could be many things-glow plug failure, stuck egr valve, needs a scan

Answer (score 1):

If it is starting but idling poorly and not revving that would suggest the glow plugs aren't the issue, I'd be thinking EGR, either the valve itself or the control solenoid. They are a bit of a pain to get to on the Tucson (unless you are taller than me!) but easy enough to clean once off the car. WD40 should do the trick.